# Замена слова с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

Есть текст, к примеру

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut @labore et dolore magna aliqua.

И вот **@labore** мне надо заменить на --labore--. Как это реализовать?

Можно разбить по словам, и пройтись `if`, а там уже как-то заменять, но может быть есть более удобный способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример, когда будет работать замена любого буквенного слова в начале которого будет символ `@`

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var text string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor inc@ididunt ut @labore et dolore magna aliqua."

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("([ \t]|^)@([A-Za-z]+)")
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(text, "$1--$2--"))
}
```

Результат:

```
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor inc@ididunt ut --labore-- et dolore magna aliqua.
```

пример работы [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/QHhhguuGTcX)

---

*Так же уточню, что собрал основную информацию в интернете, golang не    знаю.*

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно одно конкретное слово, то лучше
`strings.Replace`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

const data = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,` +
    ` sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut @labore et dolore magna aliqua.`

func main() {
    var result = strings.Replace(data, "@labore", "--labore--", 1)
    fmt.Println(result)
    // Output:
    //   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
    //   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut --labore-- et dolore magna aliqua.
}
```